# Php regex, match if { } characters isn't presented

Tags: php, regex, template-engine

I'm currently working on my own template engine for educational purposes.

Now I'm stuck at this part where I want to match if the string contains the following for e.g:

```
$article.author
```

Here's my regex pattern so far:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fx2

Current pattern matches both
`{$article.author}`
and `$article.author`.

But it should only match `$article.author`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Jumpy.

Comment: use this :- `^\$[^\|{}]*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use anchors for finding exact match as

```
^\$[^|{}]*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kE4gL6/2)**

*PHP Code*

```
$re = "/^\\$[^|{}]*$/m"; 
$str = "\$article.author\n{\$article.timestamp}"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/ZPGHMf)**

Comment: @JumpyN also, you don't need to escape `|` in character class

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you are looking for?

^\$.*

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fx3