# Regular expression capture certain characters not in quotes

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression that can capture characters that are not in quotes for example given the test string:

```
"? some ? sentence ?" ?55£$^& ?test
```

I need it to capture a question mark that is at the beginning of a string but not in quotes so `?55£$^&` and `?test` should match but not `"? some ? sentence ?"`

Comment: It totally depends on your engine. When `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` is available (e.g. in `PHP`), you can go for [`"[^"]+"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\?)`](https://regex101.com/r/kT8tV9/1)

Comment: @Jan Thanks for the response, I'm using the .NET framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work

```
(?:(?:".*?")*\s*(\?[^\s"]+))
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hO0kP6/4)**

*NOTE* :- It may give unexpected results for unbalanced `"`

Comment: If you have a quote at the beginning it highlights the characters within the quotes. "? some ? sentence ?abcd" ?55£$^& ?test

Comment: is it possible you can tweak it so that it only matches on ? if it's at the beginning of the string for example ?test but not tes?t

Comment: @ImranAzad one thing that is not clear is that for `tes?t`, there will be a match of `?t`..when do you want the match to stop?

Comment: @ImranAzad do you want something like **[this](https://regex101.com/r/hO0kP6/7)**

Comment: @rock3211987 that's the problem I was having as well. The issue is I don't want it to match on test?t. With regard to the match stopping good question, this is something I'm not sure about. Given a string "some string ?test ?test ?test)" I'd want it to search through the whole string and match on three instances in this case. Hope this helps

Comment: **[2 downvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36966112/1996394)** on two answers today..who the hell is doing it?